# How to set curl to allow HTTPS?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, self-signed

I have these code to view pdf file using PHP language.

But my PDF file is in another remote server this server have **HTTPS**.

Below code is to call the pdf file.

It works for **HTTP**. But for **HTTPS**, failed to load the document.

**Php file**

```
$cookie = 'cookies.txt';
$timeout = 30; 
$url = "https://www.test.com/viewpdf/view.pdf";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);


header('Content-type: application/pdf');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

What am I missing here ?

Appreciate if someone can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working on live server, then your code should work fine. But if you are working on localhost or dev server, then you need to set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` off as below code:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`

Hope it helps you.